# How to retrieve unique id key in database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve unique id of every Firebase new post in the query and tried this code but not works and giving wrong id

```
final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
final String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();


mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
        newPost.child("id").setValue(id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that looks suspicious is this:

```
final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
final String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
```

Every time you call `push()` it generates a new location. So if you want to capture the key/id of the new post, you should do:

```
final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
final String id = newPost.getKey();
```

I'm also not entirely sure what your listener is meant to do. If you want to simply set the two properties of the new post, you don't need a listener. Just do:

```
final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
final String id = newPost.getKey();
newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
newPost.child("id").setValue(id);
```

Or better:

```
final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
final String id = newPost.getKey();
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("title", title_val);
values.put("id", id);
newPost.setValue(values);
```